# SetWindowsHookEx makes the taskbar scrambled, while 'News and Interests' was turned off

Tags: c++, windows, hook

My OS is Windows 10 21H1, and 'Scale and layout' setting of the display is '150%' (not '100%').
I turned off the 'News and Interests' by using the context of a taskbar.

Once SetWindowsHookEx called, the notification area of the taskbar became scrambled(garbled) and the date/time area is not shown.

I called SetWindowsHookEx like below.

```
g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, CallWndProc, g_hDLL, 0 );
```

and CallWndProc is

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

How can I use the SetWindowsHookEx function to avoid the taskbar scrambled?

Sorry for my poor English and ANY help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it correct that it is caused by the SetWindowsHookEx function? 
Is this an issue that only happens on 21H1?
Please provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: As you can see in my code, the CallWinProc function does nothing special. I sure that it is caused by SetWindowHookEx.

Comment: I think it could be the 21H1's own problem.
I've experienced similar problems before.
When Win10 was first released, there was a problem that balloon tooltips were not displayed in my program.
After an OS update, it resolved itself.